# CakePHP 2: Not writing session data to database

Tags: mysql, database, session, session-state, cakephp-2.3

Is there any reason why a CakePHP 2 project won't write session data to the database (MySQL)?

As per instructions here I've created a `cake_sessions` table in the DB using:

```
CREATE TABLE `cake_sessions` (
  `id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `data` TEXT,
  `expires` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I've also modified `core.php` to reflect the following:

```
Configure::write( 'Session', [
    'defaults'       => 'php',
    // Modify Session Timeout
    'timeout'        => 1440,
    'cookieTimeout'  => 1440,
    'checkAgent'     => false,
    'autoRegenerate' => true,
] );
```

However, attempting to load pages produces session errors (failed to read session data) and no data is written to the DB.
[image: Session Error]

I've carried out similar steps in CakePHP 3 projects and it works out of the box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED.

My version of Cake was 2.8 and upgrading to 2.10.1 fixed the issue. My best guess is DB Sessions wasn’t fully implemented in 2.8!